# Stored procedure in mySQL going wrong

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to make a stored procedure for my mySQL server.

Here is my procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ClientInsertProcedure (nomClient CHAR(40), userID INT(4), tel CHAR(10), codePostal CHAR(6), noCivique CHAR(6), r CHAR(30), v CHAR(30), cred DECIMAL(6, 2))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Entreprise(nom_entreprise, telephone, code_postal, no_civique, rue, ville, credit) VALUES(nomClient, tel, codePostal, noCivique, r, v, cred) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE telephone = tel, code_postal = codePostal, no_civique = noCivique, rue = r, ville = v, credit = cred
        WHERE nom_entreprise = nomClient;
END;
```

It keep saying that i have an error on last line near `END;`

I've tried with `DELIMITER //` and it has change nothing.  I also went to mySQL website and i took the syntax there. I also looked [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893066/create-stored-procedure-in-mysqladmin). Is there any problem with the syntax itself or am i just doing it wrong?

Comment: Should there be a `WHERE` clause at the tail end of an `INSERT`? That seems wonky.

Comment: @AnthonyForloney yeah I know, but i am using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` so if the thing exists i just update it. [I found the code here](http://sql.sh/cours/insert-into/on-duplicate-key). It's in french but it roughly translate to **Enable you to UPDATE an information if it exists**. It work only in mySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how i got the code working :

1. I used `DELIMITER`
2. As pointed out by Gordon Linoff I wasn't needing a `WHERE` statement as the item was automatically selected

   > If so, you need a unique index/constraint on that column
3. The spacing after DELIMITER is **VERY** important

   ```
    DELIMITER //

   CREATE PROCEDURE sp_ClientInsert (v_nomClient CHAR(40), v_userID INT(4), v_tel CHAR(10), v_codePostal CHAR(6), v_noCivique CHAR(6), v_rue CHAR(30), v_ville CHAR(30), v_cred DECIMAL(6, 2))
   BEGIN
   INSERT INTO Entreprise(nom_entreprise, telephone, code_postal, no_civique, rue, ville, credit) VALUES(v_nomClient, v_tel, v_codePostal, v_noCivique, v_rue, v_ville, v_cred) 
       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE telephone = v_tel, code_postal = v_codePostal, no_civique = v_noCivique, rue = v_rue, ville = v_ville, credit = v_cred;
   END //

   DELIMETER ;
   ```

After some research the `DELIMITER` keyword make the code act as a single block. On the [mySQL website](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-programs-defining.html), it specifies that the string **"//"** (without quotes) after `DELIMITER` is replace by **";"** (without quotes)

> The delimiter is changed to // to enable the entire definition to be passed to the server as a single statement, and then restored to ; before invoking the procedure. This enables the ; delimiter used in the procedure body to be passed through to the server rather than being interpreted by mysql itself.

This enable a block of code to be execute as a whole.

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT**
Here is a link that explain [INSERT INTO... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) provided by Yu Yenken

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you want an update on `nom_entreprise = nomClient`.  If so, you need a unique index/constraint on that column:

```
create unique index idx_ClientInsertProcedure_nomClient
    on ClientInsertProcedure(nomClient);
```

Then, this should work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ClientInsertProcedure (nomClient CHAR(40), userID INT(4), tel CHAR(10), codePostal CHAR(6), noCivique CHAR(6), r CHAR(30), v CHAR(30), cred DECIMAL(6, 2))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Entreprise(nom_entreprise, telephone, code_postal, no_civique, rue, ville, credit)
        VALUES(nomClient, tel, codePostal, noCivique, r, v, cred) 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE telephone = tel, code_postal = codePostal, no_civique = noCivique, rue = r, ville = v, credit = cred;
END;
```

As a general rule of advice, you should name parameters to stored procedures and functions with something like `v_` so you can readily distinguish them from columns in tables.

Comment: How do i specify which entry i am updating?

Comment: You are updating the entry that violates the unique constraint.

Comment: But if my variable nom_entreprise is a `primary key` would it make it automatically `unique index` as well?

Comment: So i don't have to define it? Juste the code without the `WHERE` statement?

Answer (score 0):

you can try move away code inside, only

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ClientInsertProcedure (nomClient CHAR(40), userID INT(4), tel CHAR(10), codePostal CHAR(6), noCivique CHAR(6), r CHAR(30), v CHAR(30), cred   
DECIMAL(6, 2))

BEGIN
END;
```

if no error, that mean your insert with problem

Comment: you can try copy your query and run at your database

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html refer to this, i think you should not place where in insert on key duplicate update